# Service is not running but it is create

Tags: android, service, background, task

AndroidManifest

```
<service android:name="com.example.freewill.SensorService"
         android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

My package name is `com.example.freecallv2`.
When I try using `com.example.freecallv2` in Manifest, my app is not running, it stops as soon as I open it.

I use the following code into MainActivity to start the service, 'mSensorService' is my service class's object and 'mServiceIntent' is the Intent's object which will start the service:

```
mSensorService = new SensorService();
mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mSensorService.getClass());
startService(mServiceIntent);
```

My service object was created but after the execution, the code I used in 'onStartCommand' in my Service class is not running.

Comment: could you provide the log output, when it crashes?

Comment: What is the package name inside SensorService class?

Comment: I can't provide crash because I am running app on Bluestacks and my phone, not able to run app in Android Studio because of HAXM problem, Package name is com.example.freecallv2;